# Some cases when document.documentURI is available but not document.URL

Tags: html, url, dom

While going through the [location sources](http://code.google.com/p/domxsswiki/wiki/LocationSources) for DOM XSS attacks, I was trying to understand their differences in their usages(i.e where to use what). According to MDN, the difference between [`document.documentURI`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentURI) and [`document.URL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.URL) is following.

> HTML documents have a `document.URL` property which returns the same value. Unlike `URL`, `documentURI` is available on all types of documents.

Can anyone explain the cases where only `documentURI` is available and not `URL`?

**EDIT:**

I would like to know a few specific cases where this actually happens.

Answer (score 4):

`document.documentURI` is available on **HTML** documents and on **non-HTML** documents.

`document.URL` is available on **HTML** documents.

---

Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

  <circle cx="250" cy="250" r="50" fill="red" />

  <script type="text/javascript">
  <![CDATA[
  alert(document.URL);
  alert(document.documentURI);
  ]]>
  </script>

</svg>
```

The first alert (`document.URL`) will be `undefined`.

Comment: any specific examples?

Comment: @PraveenB: I added an example SVG document. Just open it in your browser.

Comment: how would i open this in a browser? if i save it in a file i am getting the file path for both alerts

Comment: @PraveenB: When I open the XML file with Firefox, it’s `undefined`. With Chromium, it shows the URI also with `document.URL`. Don’t know why/if Webkit/Chromium is doing something special here? (maybe it’s not really XML for them?)

Answer (score -3):

A URI (uniform resource locator) is split into a URN and URL.

URL is simply the location of the HTML document on the web, a locator along with a URN which is like a persons name or street address.

So a URI identifys and points to a file. A URL is simply the means of locating the file without a full identity (as its only part of the URI which also uses the URN).

Hope this helps